# Text expansion for LaTeX editing

Tags: substitute, replace, filetype-tex

For writing a text book I would like text expansion; on typing this:

```
|25,50,65|
```

it should expand this to:

```
$25\ux,50\uy,65\uz$
```

I tried to use simple text replacement with `:s%/TEXT/NEWTEXT/gc`, but problem is my requirement with three arguments vim should wrap some text around three arguments.

The same problem exists with `iabbrev`, plus `iabbrev` requires typing TEXT and then a space.

How can I achieve this in Vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change any set of numbers (e.g. 24,10,4 to `$24\ux,10uy,4uz$`) with something like this:

```
:%s/\v(\d+)(,\d+)(,\d+)/$\1\\ux\2\\uy\3\\uz$/g
```

Comment: I tried in ESC mode, but it says invalid argument. Pls help

Comment: @RamaKrishnaMajety Because the plus has to be escaped. Put a backslash before each one. (but I don't think *this* is the invalid argument problem)

Comment: I forgot the `:` - it's a substitution. The plus doesn't need to be escaped, since I use the very magic `\v` switch.